# Filter list by indexes

Tags: scala, functional-programming

How do I filter list by indexes stored in another list?
For instance I have the following list of values:

```
val list = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
```

and the list of indexes:

```
val indexes = List(1,2,5)
```

I want to get the following list:

```
List("b", "c", "f)
```

What is the most idiomatic way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do just:

```
indexes.map(list)
```

which is short for

```
indexes.map(index => list.apply(index))
```

Though, I would recommend to use something that is optimized for indexes (IndexedSeq).

Comment: just use: `indexes.map(list.toIndexedSeq)`

Answer (score 6):

To avoid creating too many intermediary objects, you could write

```
indexes.map(list.lift).flatten
```

With an indexed sequence, lookup time in the list would be constant. It's both idiomatic and efficient. If list is of type List, which has lookup time is O(n), then the you have O(m * n), where m is the length of indexes, and n is the length of the list.

The difference between this and `indexes.map(list)` is whether or not you want to throw an exception if an index is not found in the list.

list.lift creates a function that takes an index and returns Some(value) if it exists, and None otherwise. The `flatten` method flattens the resulting List of Option. It removes all the None results, and extracts the values from the Some results.

Comment: Would not `indexes.flatMap(list.lift)` be even more efficient?

Comment: I tried that first, but the scala compiler throws an error. I'm not sure why, hopefully someone else could explain it

Comment: yes, you are right, If you want to use flatMap you have to expand: `indexes.flatMap(list.lift(_))`.

Answer (score 3):

```
list.zipWithIndex.filter(indexes contains _._2).map(_._1)
```

Comment: I like this. But I believe using a partial function is *slightly* more readable: `list.zipWithIndex.filter( { case (_, i) => indexes.contains(i) } ).map(_._1)`

Comment: You could also use `collect` to replace the `filter` and the `map`: `collect { case (elem, i) if indexes.contains(i) => elem }`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `zipWithIndex` to add the indexes to the first list:

```
val l = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f").zipWithIndex
```

Probably better to represent the allowed indexes as a Set:

```
val indexes = Set(1, 2, 5)
```

Then simply filter based on membership of the Set and map back to the original Strings:

```
l.filter(tuple => indexes.contains(tuple._2)).map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a for comprehension as follows,

```
for ( (v,i) <- list.zipWithIndex if indexes.contains(i) ) yield v
```

Using `foldLeft` as follows,

```
indexes.foldLeft(List[String]())( (xs,i) => xs :+ list(i) )
```